# Why does changing the format of an audio file from int16 to float produce jitter?

Tags: audio-processing, scipy

I read an audio file (an instrumental music file that is mono and 16000) with wav.read (read function from scipy.io.wavfile.) This function gives me a data file in int16 format. When I change the type to float and write it again I hear a lot of jitter. Why does that happen?

Here is my script in python 3.6. [This is the music file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15-dYyD-8YIoJIaC0S1qrzkphMuEFd5Fy/view?usp=sharing).

```python
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
rate, music = wav.read("music.wav")
music = np.expand_dims(music, -1)
music_float = music.astype('float')
write("float_music", rate, music_float)
```

Comment: short answer: there's no jitter that gets produced. It's not clear what you observe. Do you mean noise? Are you familiar with the concept of *quantization noise*?

Comment: which `write` function is it that you call there? it's not `wav.write`, it seems!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hi. Thanks for your reply. What I mean by jitter is a non constant noise. And yes I used wav.write. I updated my wuestion and put importing part as well.

Comment: noise is never constant, so I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: @MarcusMüller What I mean is a kind of noise that is not a white noise. If you have time, maybe it's better to run the script and listen to it. I also put a lnk for the music. So, you can download it.

Comment: The link somehow doesn't work for me, so I'll have to take your word for it. But reading the [documentation of `scipy.io.wavfile.write`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html#scipy-io-wavfile-write) (as you've probably done): You didn't adhere to the admissible input value range, did you? I see no scaling!

Comment: @MarcusMüller  You mean when I change it to flot it should be between -1 and 1 but actually it is much higher, in the range that is suitable for int16? Thats why It is not writing properly. Tnx. I didn't notice to that.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is that `wavfile.write` supports different number ranges for different data types.

The Valid ranges are

| WAV format | Min | Max | NumPy dtype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32-bit floating-point | -1.0 | +1.0 | float32 |
| 32-bit PCM | -2147483648 | +2147483647 | int32 |
| 16-bit PCM | -32768 | +32767 | int16 |
| 8-bit PCM | 0 | 255 | uint8 |

(source https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html)

This is why Peters solution works.

Answer (score 3):

As Marcus and you say, try normalizing the float version before writing.

Changing

```
write("float_music", rate, music_float)
```

to

```
write("unit_flow_music.wav", rate, music_float/max(np.abs(music_float)))
```

seems to do the trick for me.